# Writing an MVC HtmlHelper for an IEnumerable<TModel> to display an HTML Table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I am trying to write a customer HtmlHelper that allows easy creation of an Html Table from a view being passed an `IEnumerable <TModel>` where TModel is a Model Object Type.  I would like the calling syntax from the view to be of the style:

```
@Html.TableFor(model => model.AddedUserID, model => model.ClientID......., model model => AnothreFildIWantDisplayed));
```

I am starting off by trying to get this working with one expression being passed first e.g.

```
@Html.TableFor(model => model.AddedUserID)
```

Once that works I will get the comma separated list working using params and taking more than one expression.

My View code looks like this

```
@using MyNameSpaceToMyHelper
@model IEnumerable<User>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<p>

</p>

@Html.TableFor(model => model.AddedUserID));
```

My attempt at writing an HtmlHelper is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace MyNameSpaceToMyHelper
{
    public static class GridExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString TableFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<IEnumerable<TModel>> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
        {
            var writer = new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter());

            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Table);

            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Thead);

            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Th);
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Td);

            //Colum Headers
            writer.Write(html.DisplayNameFor(expression));

            writer.RenderEndTag();
            writer.RenderEndTag();

            writer.RenderEndTag();//Close THead

            //Column Data
            //html.DisplayFor((Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>>)expression);
            foreach (ViewDataDictionary<TModel> vdm in html.ViewData.Values)
            {
                writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Tr);
                writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Td);

                //DOESN'T COMPILE
                html.DisplayFor(expression);
                writer.RenderEndTag();
                writer.RenderEndTag();
            }


            writer.RenderEndTag(); //Close Header


            return new MvcHtmlString(writer.InnerWriter.ToString());
        }

   }

}
```

This does not compile because of:

html.DisplayFor(expression);

As far as my understanding goes this is because the HtmlHelper passed to my method is for `HtmlHelper<IEnumerable<TModel>>` whereas when using `DisplayFor` it needs to be `HtmlHelper<TModel>`.

Because of this error it seems feasible that I could get this working by splitting the table header and data into two separate method calls and from my view I could call the header method then have a for loop inside the actual view which calls a method for each row or something.  Something like this

```
@using MyNameSpaceToMyHelper
@model IEnumerable<User>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<p>

</p>

@Html.TableHeadersFor(model => model.AddedUserID));
@foreach (var item in Model) {
       @Html.TableRowsFor(model => model.AddedUserID));
}
```

This should work because `TableHeadersFor` can call `DisplayNameExtensions.DisplayNameFor` which takes an `HtmlHelper<IEnumerable<TModel>>` and `TableRowsFor` could take an `HtmlHelper<TModel>` and call `DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor` with an `HtmlHelper<TModel>` so the incompatible HtmlHelper types problem would go away.

***However I do not ideally want to do this if at all possible as I want the calling syntax to be as simple as possible.  A basic premise of my question is to try and maintain a simple calling syntax without writing a for loop in the view and duplicating the expressions for choosing the columns.  The entire purpose here is to design something re-usable and as easy to use for others as possible***

I had a look in ILSpy at how `DisplayNameExtensions.DisplayNameFor` works as this handles `HtmlHelper<IEnumerable<TModel>>` as it looks like somehow an exstension method taking an `HtmlHelper<IEnuermable<TModel>>` is calling internally an extension method on `HtmlHelper<TModel>` but the code ILSpy is producing doesn't even recompile so I getting no where understanding how .Net is able to do this.

Is this possible in one extension method or will I be forced to split it compromising the calling syntax?

***UPDATE 1***
I have managed to get the following working with quite a lot of work:

```
@Html.BeginTableFor(model => model.AddedUserID
                    , model => model.Active
                    , new { @class = "grid" })


@foreach (var item in Model) {

    @Html.DisplayRowFor(model => item.AddedUserID
                        , model => item.Active)
}

@Html.EndTableFor()
```

It's not as concise as I would like and involves a heap of work especially because each expression to BeginTableFor and DisplayRowFor can return a different type meaning I have basically had to implement a method overload for any number of expressions (I've done up to 100 so will work upto 100 columns!).  This is basically the same problem they had in .Net with the Action and Func delegates where they had to write different versions for different numbers of parameters e.g. Action T1, T2,..,T16.  It's obviously extremely messy but I would rather have nice calling syntax than avoid many method overloads.

Comment: I should add I tried changing to using a VIewModel but I still ended up with incompatible HtmlHelpers between my ViewModel and Model types but if there is a way of making that work I am up for changing to use a ViewModel.

Comment: Have you looked at the MVC source code?  http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/DisplayExtensions.cs

Comment: Good idea but interesting it doesn't compile either (so it wasn't an ILSpy problem) when I paste the DisplayNameExtensions class into Visual Studio. The code that interests me for my question calls ModelMetadata.FromStringExpression(expression, html.ViewData, metadataProvider), i.e. 3 params but the method only takes 2.  I am on .Net 4.5 in my library but there are not different versios listed here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata.fromstringexpression%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: EDIT: Nevermind, I get what you're saying - you can't call the `internal` method from your helper ... Original commnent: I'm confused - the ModelMetadata.FromStringExpression takes three arguments, but there are overloads to accept less.  The full definition is in ModelMetadata.cs: `internal static ModelMetadata FromStringExpression(string expression, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider)`

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense.  I'll have a look at this source and see if I can work out how to do it.

Comment: Ok this makes more snese, in their example for DisplayNameFor they simply need the meta data for the type so they can get the display name and they ignore the actual IEnumerable of model objects. My situation is different although I want the calling syntax to be the same because I need to create a row and cells per model object using it's actual values which isn't the same as just needing the meta data about the type.  Maybe what I am trying to do just isn't possible in one extension method

Comment: Some other items to compare: https://github.com/ldiego08/Flunt.NET/tree/master/src/Flunt.Web.Mvc, http://www.aspnetwiki.com/page:creating-custom-html-helper-render-table

Comment: Thanks for the links but the implementation on aspnetwikiputs the raw HTML for the property value into the TD rather than using DisplayFor which would stop the use of templates for controlling how items are displayed later with no option to template it.  I'm trying to devise a solution which does not break other parts of the MVC framework and developers can use as though it was just built in.  Besides if I hard code the HTML with the values I can solve it because I won't need an HtmlHelper using a different type.

Comment: Hi Alan, did you manage to solve this? I'm stuck as the same point as this question.  Thanks.

Comment: @MatthewT.Baker hi I never got my own version beyond the syntax of Update 1, however I later found there was a WebGrid in MVC4+ which was roughly what I was looking for.  I've only had a basic play and it was a while ago but I think if you don't specify Columns it defaults to all as well (so you might not need as much config as these examples).  Check out these links.
https://stick2basic.wordpress.com/2013/04/23/inline-editing-with-the-webgrid-in-asp-net-mvc-4/
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/843788/WebGrid-in-ASP-NET-MVC-important-tips

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgrid%28v=vs.111%29.aspx

Comment: Will do thanks Alan.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx) for some direction and modify according to your needs.

First you need a HTML extensions like this:

```
public static class RazorExtensions {
    public static HelperResult List<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, 
      Func<T, HelperResult> template) {
        return new HelperResult(writer => {
            foreach (var item in items) {
                template(item).WriteTo(writer);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then in your HTML you can do the following:

```
{
    var comics = new[] { 
        new ComicBook {Title = "Groo", Publisher = "Dark Horse Comics"},
        new ComicBook {Title = "Spiderman", Publisher = "Marvel"}
    };
}

<table>
@comics.List(
  @<tr>
    <td>@item.Title</td>
    <td>@item.Publisher</td>
  </tr>)
</table>
```

Comment: At first I thought it was a useful technique but it doesn't actually solve the problem of having to manually specify the markup for each column and also having to manually specify the markup for the headers which is the actual problem I am trying to solve.  Then I read what WriteTo does on MSDN and it says "This type/member supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code." which is not good and bypasses templating altogether.  I have an okish solution I will update the question with but involves a lot of code.

Comment: You are going to have to define the table/row/column structure somewhere, either using markup in the razor file or programatically. I like this way because it is very flexible and allows for any sort of table structure. Doing it programatically means you will have to re-code it for each different table structure (if it changes)

Comment: My point was I don't want to have to code the table, thead, tbody, tr and td tags etc everytime.  My preferred syntax being @Html.TableFor(model => model.AddedUserID, model => model.ClientID......., model model => AnothreFildIWantDisplayed));
What I have working is close to this but involves 3 calls instead : BeginTableForm, DisplayRowFor in a loop and EndTableFor all taking expressions.  No need to specify HTML tags and supports templating.